# Android CMake build adding no-exceptions and no-rtti by default

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm attempting to convert an existing Android.mk based build to CMake and I'm having difficulty building CPP code with exceptions and rtti.  The cpp build command generated contains `-fno-exceptions` and `-fno-rtti` by default.  Adding them as `ANDROID_CPP_FEATURES` or as `cppFlags` only appends them to the build command after the default options and the build still fails.

I've searched quite a bit and aside from the few pages pertaining to CMake on Android, I get mostly old Android.mk results from the search.

There is nothing special in any of the CMakeLists.txt file, nothing that would add those options as I can tell.

None of the uncommented options below work.

**build.gradle:**

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc',
                       '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-19',
                     //  '-DANDROID_STL_FORCE_FEATURES=ON',
                       '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
                     //'-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti'
                     //'-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=exceptions',

            cppFlags "-fexceptions -frtti"
            targets  'library2'
        }

    }
```

Options in build command:

```
   <removed content> -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -frtti -fexceptions -frtti -O2 -DNDEBUG  -fPIC -MD -MT <additional content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the cppFlags do enable both the exceptions and rtti even if all four options are on the command line.  I was seeing a different error.

Comment: Appending them on command line should be ok and it should overwrite the same setting previously, in this case later ones should overwrite earlier -fno-rtti one.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and fixed it. Answer provided above.

Answer (score 1):

With the NDK toolchain r13b I'm using this combination in gradle. The part that through me off was that repeating `-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES` overwrites itself and you need a space not a comma between `exceptions` and `rtti`.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
         cppFlags '-std=c++11'
         arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang',
                 '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-19',
                 '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static',
                 '-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE',
                 '-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=exceptions rtti'
    }
}
```